# How do you use jQuery( elementArray )?

Tags: jquery

I set these up at the beginning of the script:

```
var grid = $('#grid');
var lines = $('#lines');
var background = $('#background');
```

Elsewhere in the script, I need to change the CSS for all 3 elements at the same time. Rather than doing this:

```
grid.css({...
lines.css({...
background.css({...
```

I want to do something like one of these:

```
$(grid, lines, background).css({...
$([grid, lines, background]).css({...
```

However, the only thing that seems to work is by referencing the IDs directly, like this:

```
$('#grid, #lines, #background').css({
```

I'd prefer to use references to the elements instead of the IDs directly, as they may change dynamically. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
grid.add(lines).add(background).css({...});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/xj5bb/

Comment: Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a way to add more than one jQuery object at time. This isn't terribly unreasonable, though, since jQuery objects themselves are array-like.

Comment: This is indeed working in your jsfiddle example, but not in my script. I think I have a separate variable scope issue to figure out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It works with elements, not jQuery objects.
You can use `.add()` method as said,
or `$([grid[0], lines[0], background[0]])`

see this jsfiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/HqurT/1/

(source : http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-elementarray-with-filled-elementarray )

I've maid a jsperf : http://jsperf.com/add-vs-elementarray

Answer (score 1):

save all three cached selectors in an array,

```
var elements = [grid, lines, background];
```

then loop through them when you need to:

```
elements.each(function(element){
    element.css({...})
})
```

I'd also recommend prefixing your cached selectors with a $ to make it clear what they are. :)

Comment: This isn't really idiomatic jQuery, and not all browsers support `Array.forEach()` (sadly).

Comment: This works, but it seems like there should be a simpler way without using `.each()`

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use below statement and get success.

```
$.each([$('grid'), $('line'), $('background')], function(index) {
    $(this).*jqueryAPIs(...)*;
});
```

I figure that "DOM elements wrap in a jQuery object" means element objects we get by using `$()`.

Hope this answer helps.